# How do I add electron platform to a ionic/Capacitor App

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, capacitor

I have attempted the use the https://capacitor-community.github.io/electron instructions but it appears this is really out of date with electron and matches none of the electron docs.  Is this the only best/only option for adding electron to an ionic app?  If it is what would the electron-builder.config.json look like for a target

```
"win": {"target": "appx"}
```

I would like to deploy this from the Microsoft store.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say but you should not do this. Ionic and electron are competitor products. Adding electron inside Ionic it's like saying : "How can I add a plane inside my helicopter?"
You should use one or the other, or maybe explain why and we can tell you to use Ionic OR Electron with some plugins...